# How to send an email using a Microsoft list with a button in PowerApps

Tags: powerapps

I want the "my list" in the body of the email to be replaced with a copy of my microsoft list.I have an app in powerapps, In this app I have a button i want to send a copy of the Microsoft list that is connected.

So basicly i want to have a btn with on select to send a mail with a copy of my microsoft list

I attempted to use Concat to achieve this, but I'm not entirely sure if I'm using it correctly. Currently, the following line of code is working as intended:

`Office365Outlook.SendEmail("eksamepl@gmail.com", "Test", "my list")`

This only sends a mail with the subject Test and with the body of my list. So I want the body to be a copy of the list

I got some way and this is now the code: `Office365Outlook.SendEmail( "eksamepl@gmail.com", "Test", Concat(MicrosoftList, Title & Clm2 & clm3 & clm4) )`

However now the output looks like this: 1SSRA2408true2TEST23223true

I know I can just add spaces, but that will make it still look ugly and harder to read. How do I take this the next step and send a table format of the microsft list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the HTML formatting to send an email with a table format. Below is an example code snippet that you can use in your PowerApps button's OnSelect property to achieve this:

```html
Office365Outlook.SendEmail(
    "eksamepl@gmail.com",
    "Test",
    "<html><body><table border='1' style='border-collapse:collapse;'><tr><th>Title</th><th>Column2</th><th>Column3</th><th>Column4</th></tr>" &
    Concat(MicrosoftList, "<tr><td>" & Title & "</td><td>" & Clm2 & "</td><td>" & Clm3 & "</td><td>" & Clm4 & "</td></tr>") &
    "</table></body></html>",
    {IsHtml: true}
);
```

This code uses HTML tags to structure the email content into a table format. Make sure to replace MicrosoftList, Title, Clm2, Clm3, and Clm4 with your actual variable and column names.

```
  **Key points to note in the code**:
```

1. `<table>` and `<tr>` are used to define the table structure.
2. `<th>` represents table header cells.
3. `<td>` represents table data cells.
4. Concat function is used to concatenate rows for each item in the
   MicrosoftList.

`The {IsHtml: true}` parameter in SendEmail indicates that the email body contains HTML content.

This should send an email with a well-formatted table based on your Microsoft list. Adjust the HTML code according to your list structure and formatting preferences.